# Error executing aapt: Cannot run program, CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Tags: android, eclipse, access-denied, aapt

Today I just updated the Android SDK on Windows 7 with the Android SDK Manager and started getting error during build in Eclipse which says

> "Error executing aapt: Cannot run program ... CreateProcess error=5,
>   Access is denied: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied"

I'm using Eclipse Juno and Kepler. I've also tried the bundled Eclipse that comes with Android SDK but faced the same issue everywhere.

I'm using Android build tool version 18.0.1-

Comment: Launch Eclipse as Admin.

Comment: Tried this but didn't work.

Comment: At last I updated my OS to Windows 8.1 Professional and then again installed the Android SDK from scratch and that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

Go to your eclipse folder, open eclipse.ini and add the lines

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Replace jdk1.6.0_29 with the version code of your jdk. These lines should be added above

```
-vmargs
```

Answer (score 1):

It's Windows security that's not allowing that process to run.  Here's what I did:

- Open up Windows explorer, and navigate to aapt.exe (or whatever program is supposed to run)
- Right click on it and choose "Properties"
- Go to the "Security" tab and click the "Edit" button
- Select your username in the top box and in the bottom one give "Full Control" or at least "Read & Execute"
- Click OK to get rid of these boxes

Now your user can execute that program.  Yay!